# how interrupt a program using pipe

Tags: shell

I have a problem with unix named pipes.
Consider we have a program A which writes his output to pipe (consider P),
and another program (consider B) uses this pipe as input file. The question is how can I interrupt program A externally when program B fails. 
The situation is similar to this pseudo script:

```
mkfifo P
A -output P &
B -input P &
if ( $! != 0 ) //somehow interrupt A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the PID:

```
mkfifo P
A -output P &
pidA=$!
B -input P
if ( $? != 0 )
    kill $pidA
```

`$!` expands to the PID of the most recently executed background command.

`$?` expands to the exit code.

Note for this to work, you can't run `B` in the background because you can't get the exit code for it, then.

If you still want to run it in the background, use:

```
( B -input P || kill $pidA ) &
```